# How do I define an internal assembly in a NuGet package?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, csproj

I want to define a NuGet package that contains two assemblies, one that is directly referenced by the consumer of my package and another one that is only needed at runtime and its APIs should not be visible to the consumer.

I've created a github repository to demonstrate the constellation in detail:
https://github.com/lg2de/NuGetDependencyDemo

The assembly `BaseLibrary` is directly referenced by the assembly `DependentLibrary`.
`BaseLibrary` is an external assembly not available as NuGet package.
From `DependentLibrary` my NuGet package is created.

When creating project just referencing the NuGet package, the assembly `BaseLibrary` is missing in the build output. (In the mentioned repository you can find this constellation [here](https://github.com/lg2de/NuGetDependencyDemo/tree/11962aa812a566efbb5782876692ebb1df574fa9).)
Of course, in this case the application raises an `FileNotFoundException` for `BaseLibrary`.

So I've added is to my NuGet package [using targets file directive](https://github.com/lg2de/NuGetDependencyDemo/commit/0d67ebaf3648d06322844f03a99609dd642506b7).

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)BaseLibrary.dll" Visible="false">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The assembly now available in the output folder, but I still get the same `FileNotFoundException`.
This seems to be new behavior in dotnetcore: Assemblies are not implicitly loaded.
The assembly is missing in `ConsoleWithNugetReference.deps.json`.

To solve this now have to [load manually before it is first used](https://github.com/lg2de/NuGetDependencyDemo/commit/e2dbc8c0265217164f4022347f1c7e65125e4c7a).

```cs
var location = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.Combine(location!, "BaseLibrary.dll"));
```

All this is very complicated and tedious!

So, how can I define a NuGet package that contains two assemblies, one that is directly referenced by the consumer of my package and another one that is only needed at runtime and its APIs should not be visible to the consumer?

What else have I tried:

- Adding asset attributes (like `IncludeAssets`) on the `Reference` element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing a NuGet package's dependent NuGet packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786290/removing-a-nuget-packages-dependent-nuget-packages)

Comment: No, @IanKemp, it does not. I want to ADD a reference which is NOT available as NuGet package. All the assets attributes seems not to work for `Reference` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nuget package using the below sample .nuspec file. Now you will be able to access only the APIs of DependentLibrary but not the APIs of BaseLibrary(Though DependentLibrary will be able to call BaseLibrary APIs at runtime).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
    <id>NuGetDependencyDemo</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Demo</authors>
    <owners>Demo</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Nuget Demo</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2022</copyright>
    <references>
      <!-- Assemblies which should be accessed at compile Time -->
      <reference file="DependentLibrary.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="BaseLibrary\bin\BaseLibrary.dll" target="lib"/>
    <file src="DependentLibrary\bin\DependentLibrary.dll" target="lib"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Within <references>, You can add the assemblies that you want it to be accessible at compile time

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/select-assemblies-referenced-by-projects#example